# Read accelerometer data from serial port in Python

Tags: python, numpy, serial-port, pyserial

I am a beginner to Python for importing data with Arduino. I have a program that uses pyserial library to communicate with a serial device. The program sends a byte of numbers to the machine that comes from two sensors with six channels( three channels for the accelerometer and three channels for the gyroscope).

I read data from the port and decoded them with the below code. The problem is my output which is a string. If you notice, the string started from sensorID (4 or 5), number of samples, x, y, z, g1, g2, g3, and all received data are in a string.

My code is

```
import serial
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


##
ser45 = serial.Serial('COM4', baudrate=500000, writeTimeout = 0)
config = 'n45'
k=0
while True and k<10:
  ser45.flush()
  ser45.flushInput()
  ser45.write(config.encode())
  time.sleep(1)
  ack = ser45.read(ser45.inWaiting())
  print(ack)
  # integer = int.from_bytes(bytearray(ack), byteorder='little')
  # print(integer)
  k+=1
```

Receive the data as a numpy array.

Comment: Could you provide some sample output, both from the `print(ack)` line and the `print(integer)` line (when uncommented)? And am I understanding correctly that you're wanting to convert the bytes to integers and then insert those into a numpy array?

Comment: Please include the vendor and model number of the device you are using, as well as the specifications, if available. Without such information, it will be difficult to obtain accurate advice and answers. For example, is the circuit or mode designed and configured so that the device's output data is in the string format?